# Jquery: как правильно объединить многочисленные if?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if

Есть скрипт, который сопоставляет номер вопроса с введённым в инпут ответом, и (если ответ верный) выдаёт сообщение "Yes".

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
  if(count == 1 && $('input').val() == 'answer one') {
    alert('yes!');
  }
  if(count == 2 && $('input').val() == 'answer two') {
    alert('yes!');
  }
  if(count == 3 && $('input').val() == 'answer three') {
    alert('yes!');
  }
});
```

Вопросов много. Можно ли как-то правильно объединить эти if'ы? Пробую делать через "или" - работает, но выглядит ещё хуже :(

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    if( (count == 1 && $('input').val() == 'answer one') || (count == 2 && $('input').val() == 'answer two') || (count == 3 && $('input').val() == 'answer three') ) {
    alert('yes!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответы хранить в массиве

```
var answers = ["ответ 1","ответ 2","ответ 3"];
```

Проверка через цикл

```
var allCorrect = false;    

for(var i; i < answers.length; i++) {
   if(count == i && $('input').val() == answers[i]) {
      allCorrect = true;
      console.log(`Ответ ${i} правильный!`);
   }
}

if(allCorrect) {
   console.log("Все ответы правильные!");
}
```

Comment: Точно! Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Ты можешь создать переменные и назначать им логические значения, например:

```
let answOne = count == 1 && $('input').val() == 'answer 1';
let answTwo = count == 2 && $('input').val() == 'answer 2';
let answThree = count == 3 && $('input').val() == 'answer 3';

if (answOne || answTwo || answThree) {
    alert('Yes!');

    // Ниже идет ваш код.
}
```

Так код становится читаемым и удобно редактируемым.

P.S. По заявкам: если условий `N`, которое стремиться к очень большому числу.

```
// Прогоняет все значения от 1..N и меняет значение переменной status на true
let status = false;
for (let i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
   if ( (count == i) && ($('input').val() == 'answer ' + i))
      status = true; 
}

if status {
   alert('Yes!');
} else {
   // Если не был выбран ни один из нужных вариантов. 
}
```

Comment: Ну, то есть если вопросов 100, сначала их все надо занести в переменные, а потом все 100 переменных занести в if? Читабельность - да, но кода становится сильно больше :(

Comment: @humster_spb можешь сгенирировать массив и прогнать его на true/false. Сейчас дополню ответ, чтобы ты понял.